# SSRS fails to render subreports after report and subreport are deployed

Tags: reporting-services, subreport

SSRS subreport does not display properly after deployment.

I've developed (modified actually) a report in SSRS (via Visual Studio).  The report and subreports display properly in the VS report designer, but after I deploy the reports, the main report renders properly but the two subreports fail to render.

Any ideas?

subreports render correctly when run from Visual Studio, but not after being deployed

Comment: I agree with answer from @steve-o169 this is basically path issue.
I usually work with SSRS on `Dynamics crm´ and there I deploy both reports separately but then from UI I have a option to select parent report for child report and then it shows Report correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suspect your issue stems from the path used to reference your subreports in the .rdl.  Typically, when developing a report on the local environment, it requires a full path to the subreport -- whether the .rdl for the subreport is saved on the report server or the local filesystem.  In my experience, the full path typically breaks or becomes inaccurate when the files are uploaded to the report server.  It is usually easier to use a relative path and store all .rdl files in the same folder on the report server.  For example, the differences can be demonstrated as the following.

Full path:

```
https://server/site/library/folder/Report1.rdl
C:/Reports/AllSubreports/Subreport1
```

Relative Path:

```
../AllSubreports/Subreport1
Subreport1
```

This was often the issue with my reports, though yours could have other causes.  Refer to [this Microsoft documentation link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/specifying-paths-to-external-items-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-2017) for more information.

Comment: Steve, 3 questions: 1)  I'm new to SO, how do I insert a CRLF into the comments section when I reply to you?  I'm used to using Alt-Enter   2) how do I change the path where the subreport is deployed to?  Right now, they are in the same folder as the main report, but they are not used independently, so they should go elsewhere.    3)  After deploying those two subreports to this new folder, when I set the link in the main report to those subreports, do I simply select the rdl file on the report server?

Comment: BTW, using VS 2010

Comment: See comment in this thread:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56977805/change-deployment-location-of-ssrs-report-and-sub-reports/56997232#56997232