# Change deployment location of SSRS report and sub-reports

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reporting-services

1. I need to change the destination of an SSRS report in Visual Studio 2010 so that when I deploy it, it goes to the correct folder.  There appear to be about 6 or 10 places where I can change options, I just cannot seem to find the right place to change these deployment options.
2. On this particular report, there are two subreports.  I would like to deploy these two reports to a separate (subfolder) under the folder which contains the main report.  I assume that the changes I make in #1 are for SSRS, not for a particular report (is that correct).  If so, I will need to change the path for those subreports as well.
3. Once I have the reports deployed to the correct folders, how do I change the path to these subreports in the Visual Studio report designer?  Right now, the reports render properly in the report designer, but when I go to the report server and run the main report, the subreports do not render properly.

I expect this report, along with its sub-reports to render properly from the report server.

Answer (score 1):

You can only change the deployment path in the project properties, so this affects all reports. I did try to setup a similar scenario to what you want bit to be honest it was more trouble than it was worth.

What I ended up doing was having all subreport names start with an underscore and then running a quick bit of t-sql to hide them. I don't have access to the server now but the t-sql is something like

```
USE ReportServer
UPDATE dbo.Catalog SET Hidden = 1 WHERE LEFT(Name, 1) = '_'
```

The other way you can do this is to dump all the reports in the same folder but don't give users access to it. Then Create a new folder and add linked reports in there that point back to the original versions, you can do this using the Web Portal (report manage in older versions). It's a pain as you have to do each report individually. You could probably write a script to create the catalog items for you but I've not tried that so can't comment on how easy that would be.

Answer (score 1):

So, saving the subreports to a different folder was straight forward, once I figured out where the project properties were located.  Once I deployed those to subreports, all I had to do was change the path to those subreports in the design view of the main report.

Right click on the sub-report, select subreport properties and enter the full path to the sub-report.